# Which is correct, "Questions such as these" or "Questions such as this"

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is wrong with “I don’t like these kind of things”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/what-is-wrong-with-i-dont-like-these-kind-of-things)

"Questions such as these need to be raised" 
or: 
"Questions such as this need to be raised"

MSFT Word thinks it's "this".

Comment: It depends on what precedes the sentence.

Comment: It depends on what the pronoun refers to. How many example sentences are there? If just one, use "this"; if more than one, use "these". Generally. But it really depends.

Comment: Please don't think Word knows what it's talking about!

Comment: Thanks, the sentence is preceded by 2 questions so "these" it is. Word had be second-guessing myself (as it often does).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. That question asked what made the sample sentence grammatically incorrect. This question, though, simply asks which grammatically correct sentence makes sense in context.

Comment: @MετάEd: I now agree, but I can't reverse my ill-considered closevote!

Answer (score 1):

If it is plural then the statement should be "Questions such as these," if the the statement is singular it should be "A question such as this"

Comment: Why do you think it should be "**A** question such as this"? If there's the example question (what "this" refers to), plus at least one other question like it, then that's at least two questions.

Comment: I agree with @Martha. "A question such as this" and "questions such as this" mean slightly different things. For example, you can say "I hate people like John Doe", but "I hate a person like John Doe" doesn't make much sense—why not just say "I hate John Doe".

Comment: @Peter: ["I hate a person like that"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+hate+a+person+like+that%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doesn't sound unreasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

The four permutations are...

> A. You asked Q1. Questions such as this are Off Topic.
>   B. You asked Q1. Questions such as these are Off Topic.

A - *this* = ***question*** Q1 which you have asked (or *this **type** of question*)
B - *these* = ***questions*** (of the same type as Q1).

---

> C. You asked Q1 and Q2. Questions such as this are Off Topic.
>   D. You asked Q1 and Q2. Questions such as these are Off Topic.

C - *this* = *this **type** of question*.
D - *these* = *the **questions** Q1 and Q2* (or ***questions*** of the same type)

---

There's scope to argue against B, and, to a lesser extent, C. But I believe all forms occur, and I doubt everyone who argues against some of them would necessarily notice every "transgression".

Comment: Using the singular in C doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: @James: Perhaps I should have italicised and bracketed *(You asked Q1 and Q2)* so you'd read that bit as "stage directions". It was just to set the context of *what came before*. All I'm saying is when you're casting around for something to hang *"this"* on, it's natural to come up with *this type of question* in C, since you know what you're looking for has to be *singular*.