# What kind of things ’is’ vs What kind of things ’are’

Tags: grammar

I was recently typing up a short story essay when my computer's spelling & grammar check informed me that the sentence "What kind of things are in there?" should be written as "What kind of things is in there?" I am not sure which one is grammatically correct to use. I am sure, due to subject-verb agreement that my original was correct, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does your grammar checker accept "What kinds of things are in there?"

Comment: Also closely related [What is wrong with “I don’t like these kind of things”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/what-is-wrong-with-i-don-t-like-these-kind-of-things)

Comment: It should be either "kinds of things" or "kind of thing."

Comment: It does accept ''What kinds of things are in there?'', thank you D Krueger